# Resolve return type based on param with default in typescript

Tags: typescript

How can this be resolved?

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YB4AqN4A8FgBMIYAjEEAG3gEMwA%20ACgPgDMAuGLVF6iieAJQcoAJwCu8bHniFiWAPwwwYgLYl4ImB2VqNMAD5KxFCijowA3gCgYMAJYsYTVgMs3bMEfChiRYGACM7gC%202HyS1h6e3r7%20yiYhVsEA3FZWoJCwOChwiFAMohKuMAD0JVIADvDAsDrqIungSDgBOQjQDDzhxWWV1bWq9QZGCRnNAExteQw95bhVNUa6mobxFEA)

```
const test = <T extends boolean>(def: T = false): true extends T ? number : number | null => {
  if (def) {
    return 1
  } else {
    return null
  }
};

const x = test(true)  // expect number
const x1 = test(false)  // expect number | null
const x2 = test()  // expect number | null
```

Error:

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'boolean' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'boolean'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overload your function:

```js
function test(): number | null
function test(def: false): number | null
function test(def: true): number
function test<T extends boolean>(def?: T) {
  if (def) {
    return 1 as number
  } else {
    return null
  }
};

const x = test(true)  // expect number
const x1 = test(false)  // expect number | null
const x2 = test()  // expect number | null
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgJQC5FggC2ARigE6IA+BIANnQFCiSwLLpYAmKw+wAQzpoUeWqQrVaDZuGjwkqDJh59k5EKPyEJ5WawUcMAHgAqiFAA9UYLmkQk4cOigFgAfCt4B+fKeyIAN6MiIgwwIhewAHBoaHkKFAg5EgAjIgC9jpkeqEAvhbCKEEhcQlJKdJM+Yx5ANyMjBAIGIiWiAC8RlhQGqKhAPQDFpYADijQ4jlNLVBt6V1KWIJFAYhDI+OT2ZI0hDLNYK2WAEyd3TiDw1ZbczuUe-RM+vLsSwDyo1iWvlMUADSIVS-FYiMT3KT7JgsV6KTifb6-e6A4H4XqacHEaYwthwjAIzA-bRYgFA3jnUFaP4PKolULhSKqGKleKJZJpDJZEm5RAFFBFOllNmVKGlPK1BozI5zACeC26BNSgPR-XW1zGEzu3KlrRlZ0W8K+mCViEpaw2N011MhTx1soAzOcPkbzerbtbHgwgA)

**SECOND SCENARIO, with second argument**

```js
function testOpt(x: number, def: false): number|null
function testOpt(x: number, def: true): number
function testOpt(x: number): number | null
function testOpt(): null
function testOpt(x?: number, def = false): number | null {
  if (def) {
    return 1 as number
  } else {
    return null
  }
};

const y1 = testOpt(1, true)  // expect number
const y2 = testOpt(1, false)  // expect number | null
const y3 = testOpt()  // expect number | null
const y4 = testOpt(1)  // expect number | null
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEsCmBnWB5ADrABQAeAXCpOALYBG6ATgDQoAm6o5oAhgDaboBKcpVoMAPpR48wUOElQZs%20ImQrU6TVu3Kx64QcPUMZMBMjRZcBEodH0hauyjFqpJuecVWiDydIim8hZK1sQA-LYazGygKAC8KNx8Bo4azq48KADewCgo8LGEMQLZuXko9Oiw4PSoAIwoXJipxnkAvijoyaXlFVU1qH5lbcBtANwg0MjYKACeDQleyoR1zLr6JSgA9FudxHjocC30wFOQM7MATPHB3ivMSfybO3sHRyJpLkNnFwDMN0trM9duh9odYMd0t9phDZgAWAGWZZ1YGvcGQr7gKRAA)

This behavior does not supported in TypeScript `: true extends T ? number : number | null` in a way you expect.

Related [issue 24929](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929)

Comment: Thanks, I also have optional param before def, can it be handled?

Comment: sure, pls provide an example

Comment: added to answer if you don't mind

Comment: @ZiiMakc does optional first argument affects return type ?

Comment: yes, if `number` ? `number ` :  `number | null`. But in case of example this can be omited.

Comment: what if first argument is `number` and secnd is `false`? SHuld return type be `number` or `number|null`?

Comment: `number | null`, but for answer example you can pick any

Comment: @ZiiMakc made an update